# How to plot data series with certain amount of y for each data?

Tags: plotting

I have a list of data and I want to plot this list in which each data as an x have a special y for it and not just (1,2,3,...).I want to know if it is possible to write the following lines of a Mathematica project more efficient and better?

```
    L = 14;
 Normalize[{0.03178870490109242, 0.06198339133577774, 
 0.08906997171059275, 0.11169021178262357, 0.12870983826142324, 
 0.13927541600806842, 0.14285714283663942, 0.13927541600806737, 
 0.12870983826142265, 0.11169021178262435, 0.08906997171059199, 
 0.061983391335777654, 0.0317887049010923}]
-2 Log[{0.08410500766911028`, 0.16399263889086282`, 
   0.23565699442978574`, 0.29550452425695684`, 0.34053422332707045`, 
   0.3684881145024117`, 0.3779644729549786`, 0.3684881145024089`, 
   0.3405342233270689`, 0.2955045242569589`, 0.23565699442978372`, 
   0.1639926388908626`, 0.08410500766910996`}]
p2 = ListLinePlot[{{1/L, 4.95137833910689`}, {2/L, 
3.615867473954208`}, {3/L, 2.8907558892389216`}, {4/L, 
2.4381422634779053`}, {5/L, 2.1544792988126944`}, {6/L, 
1.9966936431954139`}, {7/L, 1.94591014934237`}, {8/L, 
1.996693643195429`}, {9/L, 2.1544792988127037`}, {10/L, 
2.438142263477891`}, {11/L, 2.890755889238939`}, {12/L, 
3.6158674739542107`}, {13/L, 4.951378339106897`}}]
```

Comment: `lst = {0.03178870490109242, 0.06198339133577774, 0.08906997171059275, 
   0.11169021178262357, 0.12870983826142324, 0.13927541600806842, 
   0.14285714283663942, 0.13927541600806737, 0.12870983826142265, 
   0.11169021178262435, 0.08906997171059199, 0.061983391335777654, 
   0.0317887049010923};ListLinePlot[-2 Log[Normalize[lst]], DataRange -> {1, 13}/L]` ?

Comment: yes exactly! thank you very much

Comment: Probably you should improve the title of the question.

Comment: You can also do this. `xVal = Subdivide[1/L, 13/L, Length@lst - 1]; (*Or xVal = Range[1, Length@lst]/L*)

ListLinePlot[Transpose@{xVal, -2 Log[Normalize[lst]]}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst = {0.03178870490109242, 0.06198339133577774, 0.08906997171059275, 0.11169021178262357,
 0.12870983826142324, 0.13927541600806842, 0.14285714283663942, 0.13927541600806737, 
 0.12870983826142265, 0.11169021178262435, 0.08906997171059199, 
 0.061983391335777654, 0.0317887049010923};

ListLinePlot[-2 Log[Normalize[lst]], DataRange -> {1, 13}/L]
```

[image]

If the x values are not evenly spaced, you can create pairs of data using `Transpose`. For example,

```
xvalues = Sort[RandomReal[100, Length@lst]];
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{xvalues, -2 Log[Normalize[lst]]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: what should I do if I want a smooth plot of the above data?

Comment: @sarakaviani, by "above data" you mean  the list `Normalize[...]` or the list  `-2 Log[....]`?

Comment: I mean the final plot, -2 Log[....].

Comment: @sara, let `data = -2 Log[...]` and use `ListLinePlot[data, DataRange -> {1, 13}/L]` or use `ListLinePlot[Transpose[{Range[Length @ data]/L, data}]]`

Comment: I want to smooth the plot. I want it to have no discreetness. Your last suggestion give me the same plot as before.

Comment: @sara, try  adding the option `InterpolationOrder ->3`?

Comment: where should I add this?

Comment: sara, use `ListLinePlot[-2 Log[Normalize[lst]], DataRange -> {1, 13}/L, InterpolationOrder ->3]`

Comment: @ kglr thanks a lot!